# SEO- Title of blog not Changing

Tags: seo, google, blog, blogger

So I just created a blog on blogger last week and I decided to change the title of the blog. When I search my blog on google search the original title shows up instead of the new one.

I added my new blog's homepage on google webmaster and fetched my blog's homepage. However the title still has not changed. Is there an alternative method of doing this or am I stuck with the original title?